# Converting a script which calls another into one .exe application

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe

I am trying to convert my python scripts into an executable.

I have two .py files. The first produces a GUI (using pyqt4) to choose a csv file and select some settings. It calls another .py script though `execfile` which produces a plot using matplotlib.

I have used py2exe to convert the first file to an executable. I then have the problem that the second file is not included in the executable. Can anyone give me some advice on how to do this correctly?

If anyone has advice on another way to do it (rather that the GUI python file calling the other file) please let me know. This may well not be the correct way to do it. I'm still a novice at all this!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `execfile` just import the second file. If it's just a list of instruction put it into a function first.

```
from your_second_script import your_function
```

Comment: thanks, how do I then get that function to run though?

Comment: by calling it: `your_function()`

Comment: these are very basic things, I suggest you read some [beginner tutorials](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers)

Comment: it makes sense now, it was my understanding of now py2exe works, not the basics. It's not the easiest thing to create exe's for what I'm doing. Thanks for the link though ;)